# Empty fragment after reuse

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity with 2 buttons that serve as a menu and one fragment which has a viewpager. The fragment is being added at the activity after a button click and the views inside this fragment changes depending on the button that was clicked. Here is an example implementation:

```
Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //..
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==button1){
        fragment = new Fragment1().newInstance(ArrayStringValues1, ArrayStringValues2);
        fragmentChanger();
    }else if(v==button2){
        fragment = new Fragment1().newInstance(ArrayStringValues3, ArrayStringValues4);
        fragmentChanger();
    }
}

public void fragmentChanger(){
    FragmentManager fm2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fm2.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

If I click button 1 or 2 for the first time, the fragment and its content are being displayed successfully but when I click button 1 or 2 for the second time, the fragment's viewpager contents displays nothing.

Comment: This likely has more to do with the implementation of Fragment1 and the data you're passing into the fragment at creation. I am curious though as to why you're calling what is meant to be a static factory method (newInstance) on a freshly created object "new Fragment1()". This is more the way it's intended to be used.  http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines don't make sense (like whitaay mentioned)

```
fragment = new Fragment1().newInstance(ArrayStringValues1, ArrayStringValues2);

fragment = new Fragment1().newInstance(ArrayStringValues3, ArrayStringValues4);
```

They should read:

```
fragment = Fragment1.newInstance(ArrayStringValues1, ArrayStringValues2);

fragment = Fragment1.newInstance(ArrayStringValues3, ArrayStringValues4);
```

You should also show the code for the "fragments inside of a fragment" which will probably need getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It simplified my code as well. So dumb to instantiate a class with a static method. Lol.

Comment: It isn't dumb to instantiate a class with a static method, it just makes no sense to call a static method on an object and not on the class. Creating an object just to call a static method on it to create that same kind of object is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think this bug when use Adapter of ViewPager
    When you init adapter, @parameter getFragmentManager() -> use getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: I've never done nested fragments before so I thought the implementation would be the same. Never knew that there is an intended method for nested fragments. Thank you very much!